# Adapter update not visible rows

Tags: android, android-adapter

If you review this question [Update adapter from different method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25632167/1270400) you will see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25632407/1270400 This answer works only with visible rows.But I have to add badge to not visible and visible rows.@pomber gave a tip but I can't understand it.

How can I do this process ? I need an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to modify the child elements of a listview directly. Instead, modify the adapter so that you display the badge based on some condition.

Then, modifying the underlying data for the adapter (and calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` on the adapter) and the listview will redraw itself.

For example, consider your adapter as being backed by a list of Song objects. In `getView()` you can display the badge if `((Song) get item(position)).isFavourited()` returns true.

To display the badge for the nth Song in the list, you'd modify the list (`songs.get(n).favourite()`) and call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`.

---

edit with more detailed, but not exhaustively complete, example. Note the comments and the TODOs:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test  {

    public static void test() {
        List<Song> songsList = new ArrayList<Song>();
        songsList.add(new Song("Generic Song Title", false));
        songsList.add(new Song("Another Song Title", false));
        songsList.add(new Song("A Third Song Title", false));
        Songs songs = new Songs(songsList);

        ListAdapter songsAdapter = new SongsAdapter(songs);
        // TODO: ListView.setAdapter(songsAdapter)

        /*
        When you want to change the visibility on a badge of a given song,
        do NOT modify the view by trying to access it from the ListView
        using ListView.getChildAt(int).

        Update the data, and give it to your adapter, as follows:
         */
        List<Song> anotherSongsListWithFavourites = new ArrayList<Song>();
        songsList.add(new Song("Generic Song Title", false));
        songsList.add(new Song("Another Song Title", true));
        songsList.add(new Song("A Third Song Title", true));
        Songs modifiedSongs = new Songs(anotherSongsListWithFavourites);
        ((SongsAdapter) songsAdapter).updateSongs(modifiedSongs);
    }

    public static void test2_updateExistingSongCollection() {
        List<Song> songsList = new ArrayList<Song>();
        songsList.add(new Song("Generic Song Title", false));
        songsList.add(new Song("Another Song Title", false));
        songsList.add(new Song("A Third Song Title", false));
        Songs songs = new Songs(songsList);

        ListAdapter songsAdapter = new SongsAdapter(songs);
        // TODO: ListView.setAdapter(songsAdapter)

        /*
        Now we update the existing Songs object. The adapter's reference is 
        still pointing to it, so that data will change too, but the adapter
        won't know. This means the data will not immediately update on screen,
        unless the user scrolls up/down OR unless we tell the adapter to
        call `notifyDatasetChanged()` which we'd have to expose another method
        for because it's a `protected` method (not shown).
         */
        songs.get(0).isFavourite = true;
    }

    private static class Song {

        public final String songName;
        // not final because we're grossly modifying this for the example in test2
        public boolean isFavourite;

        private Song(String songName, boolean isFavourite) {
            this.songName = songName;
            this.isFavourite = isFavourite;
        }

    }

    private static class Songs {

        private final List<Song> songs;

        public Songs(List<Song> songs) {
            this.songs = songs;
        }

        public Song get(int position) {
            return songs.get(position);
        }

        public int size() {
            return songs.size();
        }

    }

    private static class SongsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Songs songs;

        private SongsAdapter(Songs songs) {
            this.songs = songs;
        }

        /*
            Update the dataset, and then pass the new data to the adapter.
            You could update an individual song, but I wouldn't recommmend it.
            This adapter's responsibility is to take a Songs object map each one
            to a View - it shouldn't have to deal with MODIFYING the dataset.

            Note, the `notifyDataSetChanged()`. This tells the ListView to ask
            the adapter for new views (with updated data).
         */
        public void updateSongs(Songs songs) {
            this.songs = songs;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return songs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Song getItem(int position) {
            return songs.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // we won't support stable IDs for this example
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                view = createNewView();
            }
            update(view, songs.get(position));
            return view;
        }

        private View createNewView() {
            // TODO: create a new instance of your view and return it
            return null;
        }

        private void update(View view, Song song) {
            // TODO: update the rest of the view
            if (song.isFavourite) {
                // TODO: show badge on view
            } else {
                // TODO: hide the badge on view
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you I understood the algorithm.But I need a little example code.Can you give an example for this algorithm ?

Comment: Not really. I don't know under which condition you'll show the badge. I can't see how you source your data (`getItem()`) so cannot modify it. I'll try to add a contrived example tomorrow.

Comment: I will be waiting your example.

Comment: @TolgayToklar I've updated with an almost complete example, hope this helps you understand the concept, please read the comments in the code.

Comment: @TolgayToklar was this helpful? If you have questions (about this example), feel free to ask

Comment: This is a good example thank you.I am reviewing my code for to do implement.Also can you review my adapter is it suitable for this example ? http://pastebin.com/ABL6EBGh

Comment: the second parameter you pass to the constructor of ArrayAdapter is weird to me - this is meant to be the layout resource id; if you pass 0, it suggests you're not using ArrayAdapter correctly. I think in 99% of cases, it's best to extend BaseAdapter, and supply the implementations of the abstract methods yourself (as in my example, you can see it's pretty simple)

Comment: Can you look at this ? http://pastebin.com/swNC8Tkb I am trying to do this.But I have a problem.

Comment: Open a new question and link to it here.

Comment: I did everything except update method.I didn't understand how to update an item.Can you explain update method ?

Comment: The update method in my example above is where you can bind the data to the view - this is where you'd set the text of your text views, load the images in your image views (if dynamically loading a different one), etc. In this method you have a reference to a view (a child element of the listview) and the object that you want represented by that view: it's this method's job to dress the view to reflect that data.

Comment: Thank you for information,can you update your answer with an example for update method ?

Comment: Sorry man, the update method is very specific to your model and view

Comment: No you can give an example for songs I will review this example.

Comment: I have to ask one more question.When I want add badge to individual song I have to update all songs in the list ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60779/discussion-between-ataulm-and-tolgay-toklar).

Comment: i have recyclerview with likes count and click click button if user click on any recyclerview increase the count and display to that view android