# Increment and decrement quantity of items and notify RecyclerView not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm facing a problem with the RecyclerView.
I need the TextViews to be bound in onBindViewHolder(), so the quantity value gets saved on the item's position.
The Problem is: If I scroll down, the quantity of item 1 appears at item 8 and when I scroll back it appears at item 2. Or if I increment the quantity on Position 3 and I input a new product on position 0, the quantity remains on the same Position instead at the items position. I know the views get recycled and I should call on button clicks **notifiyItemChanged(getAdapterposition());** or **notifiyDataSetChanged();** but it's not working.

(notifyDataSetchanged(); does something strange. When I click the increment button of item 2 it increments the quantity of item 1 and on scroll it gets recycled too (quantity changes position))

Here is a similar post of what I need:
[set text in textview of a list item on click of button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299911/set-text-in-textview-of-a-list-item-on-click-of-button) (answer from ataulm) I need this for the RecyclerView.
Hopefully someone can help me, it's really frustrating. Thanks in advance!

ProductList.java

```
public class ProductList extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter rvAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager rvLayoutManager;
    static ArrayList items;
    private EditText productInput;
    private TextView productQuantity;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View productView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, container, false);


        items = new ArrayList<>();
        // 13 items
        items.addAll(Arrays.asList("Wheels", "Oil", "Water", "Wax", "Paint",
                "Detergents", "Foil", "Hub Caps", "Sponge", "Brake Fluid", "Little Trees", "First Aid Boxes", "Antifreeze"));

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) productView.findViewById(R.id.recylcerview_list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManager);

        rvAdapter = new RvAdapterClass();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        productInput = (EditText) productView.findViewById(R.id.item_input);

        productInput.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (productInput.getText().length() > 0 && (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    // Perform action on key press
                    String newProduct = productInput.getText().toString();
                    items.add(0, newProduct);
                    rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    productInput.setText(null);

                    // After Keypress down focus gets back to EditText
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            productInput.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                            productInput.setFocusable(true);
                            productInput.requestFocus();
                        }
                    }, 200);

                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        return productView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    }

}
```

RvAdapterClass.java

```
public class RvAdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RvAdapterClass.ViewHolderClass> {


    public class ViewHolderClass extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView productName, productQuantity;
        Button decrementBtn, incrementBtn;


        public ViewHolderClass(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            productName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            productQuantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity_field);

            decrementBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.decrement_btn);
            decrementBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

            incrementBtn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.increment_btn);
            incrementBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.increment_btn:
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(productQuantity.getText().toString());
                    i++;
                    productQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                    notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
                    break;
                case R.id.decrement_btn:
                    i = Integer.parseInt(productQuantity.getText().toString());
                    i--;
                    productQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                    notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
                    break;
            }

        }


    }

    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {

        }
    };


    @Override
    public ViewHolderClass onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View productItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderClass(productItem);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderClass holder, final int position) {
        holder.productName.setText(String.valueOf(ProductList.items.get(position)));

//        Here is soemthing needed to bind the product quantity
//        holder.productquantity.setText("" + getQuantity(holder); isn't working because quantity doesn't change!! 


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ProductList.items.size();
    }

    private void removeItem(int position) {
        ProductList.items.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public int getQuantity(final ViewHolderClass holder) {
        return Integer.parseInt(holder.productQuantity.getText().toString());
    }

}
```

item_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="31dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/item_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="item"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recylcerview_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you are maintaining a list of items and its quantity. Firstly using a static Items list in the fragment is bad. Instead pass it in the adapter constructor. Secondly change it to a Class. Key is items and value is quantity.

```
Class Item{
String itemType;
int quantity;
}

    RvAdapterClass(ArrayList<Item> items){
    this.items = items;
    }
```

Now get the object from the list and access the values.Also when incrementing or decrementing the quantity, update the value in the appropriate object from this list.

```
 @Override 
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderClass holder, final int position) {
        holder.productName.setText(items.get(position).itemType);

//        Here is soemthing needed to bind the product quantity 
      holder.productquantity.setText("" + items.get(position).quantity);  

    }
```

The issue is because of recycling of views.

Comment: Thank you but code doesn't execute, I get an exception error: "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.test.recyclerviewdynamiclist.RvAdapterClass$Item"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Create the onresume() of the fragment, inside class ProductList.

And there implement

```
  rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: hi,  I'm not really sure because I'm not testing your code, but why you are setting always in 0 the position of items??     in your code you are setting                     items.add(0, newProduct);

Comment: Because I have an input field and when I add a new item, I want it to be on the 0th position of the list, so it gets inserted at the top instead at the bottom. But if you have any suggestions for code cleanup or other solutions, I'd love to hear them!

Comment: I'd suggest to you, add the edittext button fixed with the correct properties of xml attributes, and not to pass a position 0 to solve this, is not correct, the adapter needs to count the correct positions and to get the correct list, i guess that your troubles are coming for that, if you can , let me see with an screenshot of your list and button to understand better

Comment: Hey, here is a screenshot, hopefully it helps: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B08P4blbhrrCU1ItX3Z4aC1QSUk/view?usp=sharing