# how to set value for each item by increasing and decreasing button with respect to text view

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

`

> custom_layout

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/addition"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
   />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/qun"
    android:layout_width="33dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:background="@drawable/quantity_box"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/subtraction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/sub"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"/>
```

` here is the image what i'm getting 
[image]
here is the code  we have +button increase and -button decrease  i want to get  but  i'm unable to get the  the increase and decrease of all item except 1 items ... please help me as i have tried all thing .. thank you for your suggestion and help

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ///Description
    ImageView add, edit;
    Button ok;
    Button next2;
    ImageView addition, subtraction;
    TextView qun;
    int count = 0;
    final Context context = this;
    ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    String strCounter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        //initialization
        add = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add);
        edit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        next2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next2);


        final String items[] = {"toned milk"};
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_layout, R.id.text, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);//to register the object of list view for context menu


        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Enter new Milk");
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);// to prevent the user when he click  any where in the screen
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                dialog.show();


                //button initilazation
                Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);

                ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //initialization for edit text
                        final EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pro);
                        String data = editText.getText().toString();

                        arrayList.add(data);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "product name is :" + data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// to   refresh with update one

                        dialog.cancel();


                    }
                });


                addition = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addition);
                subtraction = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.subtraction);
                qun = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qun);

                addition.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (v == addition) {
                            count++;
                            strCounter = Integer.toString(count);
                            qun.setText(strCounter);

                        }
                    }
                });


                subtraction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (v==subtraction){
                            if (count>0)
                            count--;
                            strCounter =Integer.toString(count);
                            qun.setText(strCounter);
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

Comment: please clarify your question, it´s not really clear what exactly is not working. You have to write in understandable english please...

Comment: and it seems that you are initializing all the buttons in onClick from your addButton, you shouldn´t do this. initialize them in onCreate like you did with your other variables etc.

Comment: the problem you are getting because of this is, the onClickListeners of your addition and substraction buttons will only fire if you had clicked your add button before.

Comment: i have shared the images please go through it @Opiatefuchs

Comment: @jyoti swain, please explain your problem clearly.

Comment: i want to  manage quantity using +button &-button .. but i'm unable to do that for all the items .. nly i can increase n decrease in my 1st item @Rameshababu

Comment: @Rameshababu where is the fault i can't get . can you help me out

Comment: do you want to add/sub values from a listview item? Well, sorry but I have to tell that this is the completely wrong way to do this. You really should go through some tutorials about listviews and how to manipulate the items. For example: https://www.vlemonn.com/Blog/Android/Android-Custom-ListView-with-ImageView-EditText-and-Button/

Comment: @jyotiswain just check with this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299911/set-text-in-textview-of-a-list-item-on-click-of-button

Comment: hey can u come on team view and help me out as im trying from last 4 days still struggling @Rameshababu

Comment: Just check here [Hope this will help to solve your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31300420/2556660)

Comment: here i have to get items from user  by using custom Dialog box @Rameshababu

Comment: @jyotiswain kindly follow the above mentioned answer.

Comment: @Rameshababu still not able to do

Comment: @jyotiswain are you tried the given answer.

Comment: @Rameshababu yes still not able to have it can u help me out please

Answer (score 0):

You should set OnClickListener to your +buttons and -buttons of every ListView item. You can do this by Override the getView() method of ArrayAdapter and write you own implementation. eg:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if(convertView == null){
        // inflate your view
    }else{
        addition = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addition);
        subtraction = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subtraction);
        qun = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qun);
    }
}
```

Please refer to an example here: [Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)