# How do you create a static table in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android programming from iOS and I need to create a static table. This is simple in iOS with the use of static cells but is there such a thing in Android?

To be more precise of what I need, each row has 3 columns, a TextView which is just a name, an EditText which is the number of units and a final TextView which is the number of units multiplied by some constant.

The way I currently understand ListView's in Android is that I need to make a custom Adapter which will read in all the string constants from strings.xml. If I do this however, I may be able to load the table visually as I need it, but then when a EditText value is changed, how would I be able to handle that and edit the text of the corresponding TextView? I need each row to be independent and be able to set ID's for every element in the row so I can access and edit them but this doesn't seem possible by just reading in values from string.xml.

Sorry that there is no code given here, as I am new to Android and don't know where to start. If you could please include some code in your answer, that would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the size of the table is not known (and even if it is known, it still might be preferable) it's best to use a ListView (or RecyclerView now, with a LinearLayoutManager).

A ListView/RecyclerView is a view of many items of usually the same type of data. The component which binds each datum to a row, as you've said, is the  Adapter.

With regards to saving the information as the user scrolls through the list, you should update your data source. This can be done:

- immediately, after each piece of data is entered
- as each row scrolls off screen, that row data can be saved (search for: on view recycled) + when the user leaves the screen

---

I'd recommend using a RecyclerView and extending RecyclerView.Adapter, but you can do the same thing with ListView and extending BaseAdapter, and is quite easy to switch between.

Then I'd create a model class which will represent each row: this should include fields for each of the three columns, e.g.:

```
class Item {

    private final String name;
    private final int units;
    private final int result;

    Item(String name, int units, int result) {
        this.name = name;
        this.units = units;
        this.result = result;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    int getUnits() {
        return units;
    }

    int getResult() {
        return result;
    }

}
```

Then your adapter would hold a `List<Item>` as a field. Note that although the result can be calculated given the unit and number of units, it's not the responsibility of the Adapter to do this - it should be pretty dumb, and consequently pretty simple, merely creating Views when it's asked, and binding Views to an item at a given position when it's asked too.

---

- [Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653905/adapter-update-not-visible-rows/25654089#25654089) where OP asked how to edit the items of a ListView (with ListAdapter) and persist the changes as the user scrolled up and down.
- [ListView, callback when a View is recycled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.RecyclerListener.html) (scrolled off screen)
- [RecyclerView, callback when a View is recycled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.RecyclerListener.html)